# Handling Print Preview Closing Event in Word

Tags: ms-word, print-preview

I want to use Word's print preview window for previewing and printing Word documents. I am using code like this (that works well):

```
wordApplication.Visible = true;
document = wordApplication.Documents.Open(documentPath);
document.PrintPreview();
```

But when user closes print preview window he see the Word's main window. How I can to handle print preview closing even to hide Word's application?

Answer (score 1):

you can use this code to close any window in word

```
Windows("Your document name").close
```